# How can i browse home computer files remotely or from web interface

Tags: windows-7, file-management, remote-access

I have data on external USB dribe around `5TB`.

I want that should be able to browse my external drives from web interface and download some files if i need.

Is there any software / website to do that. Even if it just allows me to browse through folders, that will be fine also for time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a few things, all requiring it to be plugged into a computer that can act as a server. Assuming you want access from outside your network: You'd also need to port forward on your router to that machine for the chosen protocol's port, you can use a different external port and forward to the local machine's protocol port.

Fairly Insecure:

1. FTP Server (port 21) - Set up a basic ftp server and share the USB drive's content via FTP.
2. Web Server (port 80) - Set up a web server, you can then allow indexing of the files on your drive

Much More Secure:

3. SSH Server (port 22) - This requires an ssh client, but you could just ssh in and do some `cd`, `ls`, and `scp` to look around and copy stuff to/from.
4. SFTP Server - Above FTP but the secured one.
5. Set up your own version of drop box using [Owncloud](http://owncloud.org)

Comment: thanks, i have installed owncloud with wampserver on windows 7. how can i put my external drives to show in web interface